# jq argjson does not work with string from variable

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to create a json with jq

```
f=1
jq -n --argjson a ${f} '{"test":$a}'
```

or

```
f="1"
jq -n --argjson a ${f} '{"test":$a}'
```

or

```
jq -n --argjson a "teststring" '{"test":$a}'
```

work fine

but

```
f="teststring"
jq -n --argjson a ${f} '{"test":$a}'
```

yields
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers
Gordon

Comment: Your third example (passing `"teststring"` inline) doesn't actually work. Do you actually want to pass JSON or just a string?

Comment: you're right
This works 

 jq -n --argjson a '"teststring"' '{"test":$a}'

Comment: Actually,  I am trying to create a json from an array of strings
E.g. 
["path1","path2","path3"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is interpreting the double quotes and passing bare strings to `jq`.

The correct way to define your input is to add an extra level of quoting to make the double quotes part of the value:

```bash
f='"teststring"'
jq -n --argjson a "${f}" '{"test":$a}'
```

As shown, you also need to quotes around the use of `$f` in case it contains whitespace.

Comment: Or simply use --arg, e.g. `jq -n --arg a "$f" ....`

Comment: Many thanks! It works!

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. I tested on zsh without quotes around `$f` first and it worked, but bash doesn't work

Comment: Interesting! sh, bash, dash, ksh all require quotes. Surprised that it's different in zsh. ( But I verified that it's true :) )